# What is a "ubuntu" gnome-session and why isn't it a `systemd --user` session?

Tags: 18.04, gdm

The content of `/usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu.desktop` states that:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Ubuntu
Comment=This session logs you into Ubuntu
Exec=env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu gnome-session --session=ubuntu
TryExec=gnome-shell
Type=Application
DesktopNames=ubuntu:GNOME
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-session-3.0
```

From `Exec`, I see that the Linux shell environmental variable `GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE` is given the value `ubuntu` and the binary `/usr/bin/gnome-session` is told to run a `ubuntu` session.

Questions: What is a `ubuntu` session? Why isn't it a `systemd --user` session as is mentioned in [GDM's documentation](https://wiki.gnome.org/Initiatives/SystemdUser)?

Comment: If you look a the comments in the documentation's linked bug report, you will see that a few blockers remained while 18.04 was being put together. So --user level integration was incomplete for 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

According to Ubuntu's documentation, [gnome-session](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/gnome-session.1.html) is a program to start a GNOME desktop environment. Also, the option `--session=SESSION` means to use the applications defined in `SESSION.session`. And, if not specified, `gnome.session` will be used.

Accordingly, `--session=ubuntu` should refer to the file `/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/ubuntu.session` which writes:

```
[GNOME Session]
Name=Ubuntu
RequiredComponents=org.gnome.Shell;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.A11ySettings;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Clipboard;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Datetime;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Housekeeping;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Mouse;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.PrintNotifications;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.ScreensaverProxy;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Smartcard;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sound;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings;
```

According to @user535733 comment, while 18.04 was being put together, there were issues and `systemd --user` level integration was not done for 18.04.